# login to facebook using fb API in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am stuck in using facebook API in WindowsPhone8.1, i am unable to create a login button and authenticate user in WP8.1, and i couldnt search relative material on google too, even though i have done the same task in Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8 but not in Windows phone 8.1
here is my code that i have used for login process

```
App.fb.session = await App.fb.sessionclient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream,publish_action");
App.fb.AccessToken = App.fb.session.AccessToken;
App.fb.FacebookID = App.fb.session.FacebookId;
App.fb.expires = App.fb.session.Expires;
```

but i give "No Implemented" Exception

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about whether the WP8.1 has integrated the `Facebook` Authentication. As mentioned [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/facebook-integration-removed-in-windows-phone-81/39e02476-b9e4-46f7-8867-629d58274492) it's still not.